# Removing all Category pages with one exception

Tags: functions, categories

I am using this code to remove all category pages, however I wish to retain a certain category with ID number 20. How may I do this please?

```
// Remove category archives
add_action('template_redirect', 'jltwp_adminify_remove_archives_category');
function jltwp_adminify_remove_archives_category()
{
    if (is_category()){
        $target = get_option('siteurl');
        $status = '301';
        wp_redirect($target, 301);
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the `if (is_category()){` line:

```
// Remove category archives
add_action('template_redirect', 'jltwp_adminify_remove_archives_category');
function jltwp_adminify_remove_archives_category()
{
    // Ignore category 20.
    if (is_category() && !is_category(20)){
        $target = get_option('siteurl');
        $status = '301';
        wp_redirect($target, 301);
        die();
    }
}
```